# Why is the sum function improperly rounding two floats

Tags: python

Why is python returning `5.789999999999999` for `sum([1.23, 4.56])` and how do I get it to return the expected `5.79`

Comment: Use `round` with 2 as the second parameter to round to two decimal places. Otherwise floating point error will be there.

Comment: I don't know that the values will always have two decimal places

Comment: Thomas - that isn't python specific. I am asking the best practice in python

Comment: @newToScala if you need precise decimal values don't use `float` objects, which cannot precisely represent those values, and which rely on floating point arithmetic. Use `decimal.Decimal` objects.